# Problems looping to prompt for another password

Tags: tcl, expect

I need some help with an EXPECT script please....

I'm trying to automate a login, prior to accessing a load of hosts, and cater for when a user enters a password incorrectly.  I am getting the username and password first, and then validating this against a particular host.  If the password is invalid, I want to loop round and ask for the username and password again.

I am trying this :-

(preceding few irrelevant lines omitted)

```
    while {1} {
            send_user "login as:- "
            expect -re "(.*)\n"
            send_user "\n"
            set user $expect_out(1,string)
            stty -echo
            send_user "password: "
            expect -re "(.*)\n"
            set password $expect_out(1,string)
            stty echo

            set host "some-box.here.there.co.uk"
            set hostname "some-box"
            set host_unknown 0
            spawn ssh $user@$host
            while {1} {
                    expect {
                            "Password:"     {send $password\n
                                            break}
                            "(yes/no)?"     {send "yes\n"}
                            "Name or service not known"     {set host_unknown 1
                                                            break}
                            }
                    }
            if {$host_unknown < 1} {

                    expect {
                            "$hostname#"    {send "exit\r"
                                            break
                                            }
                            "Password:"     {send \003
                                            expect eof
                                            close $spawn_id
                                            puts "Invalid Username or Password - try again..."
                                            }
                            }
                    } elseif {$host_unknown > 0} {

                            exit 0}
            }
    puts "dropped out of loop"
```

And now I can go off and do lots of stuff to lots of boxes .....

This works fine when I enter a valid username or password, and my script goes off and does all the other stuff I want, but when I enter an invalid password I get this :-

> Fred@Aserver:~$ ./Ex_Test.sh ALL
>
> login as:- MyID
>
> password: spawn ssh MyID@some-box.here.there.co.uk
>   Password:
>
> Password: 
>   Invalid Username or Password - try again...
>   login as:- cannot find channel named "exp6"
>
> ```
> while executing  "expect -re "(.*)\n""
> invoked from within  "if {[lindex $argv 1] != ""} {
>     puts "Too many arguments"
>     puts "Usage is:-  Ex_Test.sh  host|ALL"
> ```
>
> } elseif {[lindex $argv 0] != ""} {
>
> ```
>     while {1} {
>     ..."
> (file "./Ex_Test.sh" line 3)
> ```

Its the line "can not find channel named "exp6" which is really bugging me.

What am I doing wrong?  I am reading Exploring Expect (Don Lines) but getting nowhere....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever `expect` is supposed to wait for some word, it will save the `spawn_id` for that expect process into `expect_out(spawn_id)`.

As per your code, expect's spawn_id is generated when it encounters

```
        expect -re "(.*)\n"
```

When user typed something and pressed enter key, it will save the expect's spawn_id. If you have used expect with debugging, you might have seen the following in the debugging output

```
expect does "" (spawn_id exp0) match regular expression "(.*)\n"
```

Lets say user typed 'Simon', then the debugging output will be

```
expect: does "Simon\n" (spawn_id exp0) match regular expression "(.*)\n"? Gate "*\n"? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Simon\n"
expect: set expect_out(1,string) "Simon"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp0"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Simon\n"
```

As you can see, the expect_out(spawn_id) holds the `spawn_id` from which it has to expect for values. In this case, the term `exp0` pointing the standard input.

If `spawn` command is used, then as you know, the tcl variable `spawn_id` holds the reference to the process handle which is known as the spawn handle. We can play around with `spawn_id` by explicitly setting the process handle and save it for future reference. This is one good part.

As per your code, you are closing the ssh connection when wrong password given with the following code

```
close $spawn_id
```

By taking advantage of `spawn_id`, you are doing this and what you are missing is that setting the `expect`'s process handle back to it's original reference handle. i.e.

```
While {1} { 

    ###Initial state. Nothing present in spawn_id variable ######
    expect "something here"; #### Now exp0 will be created  

    ###some code here ####

    ##Spawning a process now###

    spawn ssh xyz ##At this moment, spawn_id updated

    ###doing some operations###
    ###closing ssh with some conditions###
    close $spawn_id

    ##Loop is about to end and still spawn_id has the reference to ssh process  
    ###If anything present in that, expect will assume that might be current process
    ###so, it will try to expect from that process
```

}

When the loop executes for the 2nd time, expect will try to expect commands from the `spawn_id` handle which is nothing but ssh process which is why you are getting the error

```
can not find channel named "exp6"
```

Note that the "exp6" is nothing but the spawn handle for the ssh process.

**Update :**

> If some process handle is available in the
>   `spawn_id`, then `expect` will always expect commands from that
>   process only.

Perhaps you can try something like the following to avoid these.

```
#Some reference variable 
set expect_init_spawn_id 0

while {1} {

    if { $expect_spawn_id !=0 } {
            #when the loop enters from 2nd iteration,
            #spawn_id is explicitly set to initial 'exp0' handle
            set spawn_id $expect_init_spawn_id 
    }

    expect -re "(.*)\n"
    #Saving the init spawn id of expect process
    #And it will have the value as 'exp0'
    set expect_init_spawn_id $expect_out(spawn_id)
    spawn ssh xyz

    ##Manipulations here

    #closing ssh now
    close $spawn_id
}
```

This is my opinion and it may not be the efficient approach. You can also think of your own logic to handle these problems.

Comment: Brilliant! A very clear explanation, and it all makes sense now. Problem resolved, and I'm able to crack on. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to store the `$spawn_id` as a temp variable before a nested `expect` command, then set the `$spawn_id` to the temp variable after a nested `expect` command.

Also, get rid of the `while {1}` loops. They are not needed because `expect` behaves like a loop provided you use `exp_continue` whenever you don't wish to exit. You don't need `expect eof` nor do you need `close $spawn_id`. I don't use them in the following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set domain [lindex $argv 0];

set timeout 300
spawn ./certbot-add.sh $domain
expect {
    "*replace the certificate*" {
        send "2\r";
        exp_continue;
    }
    "*_acme-challenge*" {
        puts [open output.txt w] $expect_out(buffer)
        spawn ./acme-add.sh $domain
        set tmp_spawn_id $spawn_id
        expect {
            "$ "
        }
        set spawn_id $tmp_spawn_id
        send "\r";
        exp_continue;
    }
    "*certificate expires on*" {
        puts "Certificate Added!"
    }
}
```