# Expect script error send: Spawn id exp4 not open while executing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

I'm trying to run this script but having different errors when modified. Here is the code and the output. Please help.

Updates at the end of the post with debug info

```
    #!/bin/bash
    (( $# != 1 )) && { echo >&2 "Usage: $0 \"[COMMAND]\""; exit 1; }
    servers_addresses=(10.10.10.10 )
    for server_address in ${servers_addresses[@]}; do
    expect <<EOF
    spawn ssh -t root@$server_address "$*"
    expect -timeout 2 "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\n" }
    expect "s password:" { send "Correct_Password\n" }
    expect "s password:" { send "Wrong_Password_22222\n" }
    expect "s password:" { send "Wrong_Password_33333\n" }
    expect eof
    EOF
    done
```

And the output is like:

```
    goldberg188@Test-Server ~$ ./test.sh "sudo cat /etc/hosts"
    spawn ssh -t root@10.10.10.10 sudo cat /etc/hosts
    root@10.10.10.10's password:
    # Do not remove the following line, or various programs
    # that require network functionality will fail.
    10.10.10.10             TEST-004 localhost.localdomain localhost
    ::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
    Connection to 10.10.10.10 closed.
    expect: spawn id exp4 not open
        while executing
    "expect "s password:" { send "Wrong_Password_33333\n" }"
```

If I modify like this, then the output would be bit different

```
    expect "s password:" { send "Wrong_Password_11111\n" }
    expect "s password:" { send "Correct_Password\n" }
    expect "s password:" { send "Wrong_Password_33333\n" }

    goldberg188@Test-Server ~$ ./test.sh "sudo cat /etc/hosts"
    spawn ssh -t root@10.10.10.10 sudo cat /etc/hosts
    root@10.10.10.10's password:
    # Do not remove the following line, or various programs
    # that require network functionality will fail.
    10.10.10.10             TEST-004 localhost.localdomain localhost
    ::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
    Connection to 10.10.10.10 closed.
    expect: spawn id exp4 not open
        while executing
    "expect eof"
```

And if the correct password in on the third line then no errors at all. Works fine on this one.

```
    expect "s password:" { send "Wrong_Password_11111\n" }
    expect "s password:" { send "Wrong_Password_22222\n" }
    expect "s password:" { send "Correct_Password\n" }


    goldberg188@Test-Server ~$ ./test.sh "sudo cat /etc/hosts"
    spawn ssh -t root@10.10.10.10 sudo cat /etc/hosts
    root@10.10.10.10's password:
    # Do not remove the following line, or various programs
    # that require network functionality will fail.
    10.10.10.10             TEST-004 localhost.localdomain localhost
    ::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
    Connection to 10.10.10.10 closed.
```

Update: Debug info - Modified to

```
    exp_internal 1
    expect "s password:" { send "Wrong_Password_11111\n" }
    expect "s password:" { send "Correct_Password\n" }
    expect "s password:" { send "Wrong_Password_33333\n" }
```

Output:

```
    goldberg188@Test-Server ~$ ./test.sh "sudo cat /etc/host"
    spawn ssh -t root@10.10.10.10 sudo cat /etc/host
    root@10.10.10.10's password:
    expect: does "root@10.10.10.10's password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "s password:"? yes
    expect: set expect_out(0,string) "s password:"
    expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
    expect: set expect_out(buffer) "root@10.10.10.10's password:"
    send: sending "Wrong_Password_11111\n" to { exp4 }

    expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "s password:"? no


    expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "s password:"? no
    Permission denied, please try again.
    root@10.10.10.10's password:
    expect: does " \r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\r\nroot@10.10.10.10's password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "s password:"? yes
    expect: set expect_out(0,string) "s password:"
    expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
    expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\r\nroot@10.10.10.10's password:"
    send: sending "Correct_Password\n" to { exp4 }

    expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "s password:"? no


    expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "s password:"? no
    cat: /etc/host: No such file or directory
    Connection to 10.10.10.10 closed.

    expect: does " \r\ncat: /etc/host: No such file or directory\r\r\nConnection to 10.10.10.10 closed.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "s password:"? no
    expect: read eof
    expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
    expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\ncat: /etc/host: No such file or directory\r\r\nConnection to 10.10.10.10 closed.\r\r\n"
    expect: spawn id exp4 not open
        while executing
    "expect eof"
```

Comment: note: same question on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/q/642129/30957

Answer (score 3):

As per your code, it looks like the `ssh` connection got closed after the few trails of giving the passwords to ssh session.

Whenever a new process spawned with `spawn` command, then `expect` will save the `spawn_id` for that expect process into `expect_out(spawn_id)`.

As per your code, expect's spawn_id is generated when it encounters

```
        spawn ssh -t root@$server_address "$*"
```

The debug which you have seen as below.

```
 spawn ssh -t root@10.10.10.10 sudo cat /etc/host
    root@10.10.10.10's password:
    expect: does "root@10.10.10.10's password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "s password:"? yes
    expect: set expect_out(0,string) "s password:"
    expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
```

As you can see in the debug information, the `expect_out(spawn_id)` holds the `spawn_id` from which it has to expect for values which is `exp4` in your case.

As you can see, the connection got closed after few wrong trails thereby making the process `exp4` no longer exits in the context. Since the `spawn_id` holds the reference to the same, expect will try to expect from that process and failed.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25649995/974155) question to know about how this `spawn_id` being used with standard input (which is reading input from console)

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed after I got some info from 
https://serverfault.com/questions/642129/expect-script-error-send-spawn-id-exp4-not-open-while-executing

Thanks to https://serverfault.com/users/30957/glenn-jackman