# How to continue if expected string does not appear?

Tags: bash, expect

I am using `expect` script in order to install some packages. During such installations, sometimes it asks for permissions say `Y/n` to install them and sometimes it doesn't.

I have 2 questions here :

1 ) How to take care of both these cases?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
# This is for boto libraries installation
spawn apt-get install python-pip 
expect { 
    "Do you want to continue" 
        {   send "Y\r\n"  ## HERE SOMETIMES THIS STRING MAY NOT APPEAR
        }
}
interact
spawn pip install filechunkio 
interact
spawn pip install -U boto 
interact
```

When expect string does not appear, it throws error as

```
spawn_id: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"interact"
    (file "./botoInstall.exp" line 10)
```

line 10 is the first interact.

2 ) Here what does `spawn_id: spawn id exp6 not open` mean?

Comment: Does passing `-y` to `apt-get` not do what you want here without all this mess? For the `apt-get` step at least.

Comment: For 1) see Dinesh's answer. For 2) it's because the expected string did not appear so the `expect` command would return only on `timeout` or `eof`. Since the `apt-get` command would usually finish very quickly (<10s) so the `expect` command would see `eof` which means the spawned `apt-get` process has already exited so the `interact` command would definitely fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `exp_continue` to have an optional string in `expect` to wait for it. The above script can be modified as

```
spawn apt-get install python-pip 

expect { 
    "Do you want to continue" {   send "Y\r\n"; exp_continue }
    #some other expect string along with 'exp_continue'
    timeout { puts "timeout happened" }
    eof { #some other action here# } 
}
```

If `expect` sees those words, it will send `y\r\n`, else it will proceed to check for other strings.

Remember to have some exit criteria in the `exp_continue` usage. Else, obviously timeout will happen if none of them seen within the time limit.

With respect to your query on the `spawn id exp6 not open`, have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760913/expect-script-error-send-spawn-id-exp4-not-open-while-executing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645826/problems-looping-to-prompt-for-another-password/).

Comment: I'm not sure `exp_continue` is the relevant detail here. I think the `timeout` is. Though you need `exp_continue` if there are other strings to match in that same block.